# Can you help with the set identification for these items? Symmetrical greyish wings, and tan/brown internals

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

Can you help with the set identification for these items?

[image: Symmetrical greyish wings, and tan/brown internals]

Answer (score 3):

The left two assemblies are from

[8095: General Grievous' Starfighter](https://brickset.com/sets/8095-1/General-Grievous-Starfighter)
[image]

keypart:

- [Dark Bluish Gray Wedge 2 x 16 Triple](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30382&colorID=85&in=A)

The right assembly is from :
[75234: AT-AP Walker](https://brickset.com/sets/75234-1/AT-AP-Walker)
[image]

Keyparts :

- [Dark Bluish Gray Dish 3 x 3 Inverted (Radar](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43898#T=C))
- [Reddish Brown Tile, Modified 2 x 2 with Studs on Edge](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=33909#T=C)